# Does it matter if state variables are assigned value in line or in the constructor?

Tags: solidity, constructor, state-variable

For example, is there a difference between these two snippets of code, or is there a best practice? From my experimentation, it doesn't seem like it makes a difference. Thanks.

```
contract A {

uint public a;
uint public someInput;


constructor(uint _someInput) {
    a=5;
    someInput = _someInput;
}

function setA(uint _a) external {
    a = _a;
}  
}

contract A {

uint public a = 5;
uint public someInput;


constructor(uint _someInput) {
    someInput = _someInput;
}

function setA(uint _a) external {
    a = _a;
}
}
```

Comment: Note that if you're using upgradeable contracts, whether you initialise the variables inline or in the constructor [matters a great deal](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/writing-upgradeable#avoid-initial-values-in-field-declarations).

Answer (score 1):

Be careful assigning values from functions that read state. If you call the function to initialize a variable before the dependent variable in the function is initialized you may get indeterminate results..

i.e.

```
contract Example{
    uint public a=getB();
    uint public b=0;

    function getB() public view returns(uint B){
        B=b; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both works. Assigning variables inside the `constructor` method would cost you more gas when deploying the contract. It is better to assign it inline unless you do not need a param from the constructor.